# Angular 2+ subscribe error this context

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have this code, which calls REST API:

It is method in component called

```
load(loadParams: IDatatableLoadEvent): void {
  this.loading = true;
  this.productService.loalProducts(loadParams.sortBy, loadParams.currentPage, loadParams.pageSize, loadParams.searchTerm, loadParams.sortOrder.toLowerCase())
    .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IProduct[]>) => {
      this.filteredData = res.body;

      // we have to set x-pagination to COSR rules on API server
      const xPagination = res.headers.get('x-pagination');
      this.filteredTotal = JSON.parse(xPagination).totalCount;

      this.loading = false;
      // Hack - because we are setting loading and until data are loaded
      // we have to stop changeDetection and tell angular when to detect changes
      // - this happens only when we are changing pagesize
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }, error => {
      this.loading = false;
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Problem is when I get an error, the error handle event get fired, but **this** context isn't the component, but **SafeSubscriber**

Comment: Where are you calling `load()`? I bet if you add `this.load = this.load.bind(this)` to the constructor of the class `load` is a property of, the problem will go away. My assumption is that you are calling `load` inside an observable, so you are passing it as a function somewhere. That is where the `SafeSubscriber` context comes from.

Comment: The problem will be probably somewhere else because if you're using `=>` it captures `this` context.

Comment: there's insufficient info to detect the issue, please provide the code to `loalProducts` and to the place where `load` is called

Comment: here is demo I created [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-covalent-custom-datatable) Load method is in appComponent and it's transmitted to DataTable as event

Comment: compilation in ES2015 have some trouble in particular case for `this` context. I can't find where i have see this. but you can just deal with `const self = this`  on the top of `load()`method, then use `self. loading = false;`